# Customize all image captions

Tags: images, theme-customizer, captions, svg

Is there anyway to **add** smth like a **SVG** to all **image captions** of my website?
Smth like the camera logo under this photo.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether the captions are using the same CSS class or HTML tag, you can add a `:before` pseudo element to the CSS. This will add an image before every `<caption>` tag on your website.

```css
caption:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('your-image-url-here');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the WordPress glyph icons, try the following:

```css
caption:before {
    content: '\f129';
    font-family: dashicons;
}
```

And don't forget to enqueue the dashicons in your `functions.php` file:

```php
function enable_frontend_dashicons() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enable_frontend_dashicons' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanna use a **dashicon** like this: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#camera-alt

Comment: @PooryaGhorbani You'd just need to click the "Copy CSS" button on that page next to the glyph, and add that into the `content:` attribute. Answer edited to include that.

Comment: Thank u so much, u are the best.